# Restore data from a corrupted .img file

Tags: windows, iso-image, ramdisk

After having formatted my PC, I forgot to setup backup on my ramdisk.

I've been using dataram ramdisk which stores the disk in a .img file on exit.

However my PC crashed recently and now this .img is corrupt. I can't mount it with windows or extract it with 7 zip. On the disk I have a programming project so in other words a lot of text files.

Is there any software that allows me to extract parts of the .img thats not corrupt?

I've tried, Norton-Ghost, Acronis true home image and IsoPuzzle but neither seem to support .img files. I've also tried roadkil´s unstoppable copier, but it doesn't extract the contents.

Comment: You're probably hosed...I probably shouldn't ask, but I must: why would you store anything you care about on a ramdisk?

Comment: Take a look at dd_rescue.

Comment: @DavidJensen You might do better to save your files to the hard disk, and then populate the RAM disk as an initial step prior to compilation. In the meantime, you could use a free VM tool such as VMWare Player to run up a Linux virtual machine in which to run dd_rescue on the .img file.

Comment: Try WinImage and see if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for you, but photorec is free software which will scan the image loking for recoverable data based on file signatures, and will hep recover data.